# Differential equation system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Solve following differential equations system:
$$\overline{x}'(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 3&-2 \\ 4&-1 \end{bmatrix} \overline{x}(t)$$

I don't have answer to this task, so I will be grateful if you could check my solution.

We have eigenvalues $t_1 = 1-2i, t_2 = 1+2i$ hence eigenvectors is for example $v = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1-2i \end{bmatrix}$. So we find solutions of differential equations system by $$e^{(1+2i)t} v = e^t \cdot e^{2it} v = e^t \cdot (\cos(2t) + i \sin(2t)) \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1-2i \end{bmatrix} = \\ e^t \cdot  \begin{bmatrix} \cos(2t) \\ \cos(2t)+2 \sin(2t) \end{bmatrix} + e^t \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \sin(2t) \\ \sin(2t) - 2 \cos(2t) \end{bmatrix}i$$. Thus we have

$$\overline{x}(t) = C_1 \cdot e^t \begin{bmatrix} \cos(2t) \\ \cos(2t)+2 \sin(2t) \end{bmatrix} + C_2  \cdot e^t \begin{bmatrix} \sin(2t) \\ \sin(2t) - 2 \cos(2t) \end{bmatrix}$$

Thanks in advance for check it!

Comment: I've updated your solution by changing $e^{1+2i}$ to $e^{(1+2i)t}$, which I think is what you meant to write. Let me know if that is not the case.

Comment: Your eigenvector is incorrect.  It should be a multiple of$$\left[ \begin{matrix}{-\alpha\\(-1+i)\alpha}\end{matrix} \right]$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: as anorton mentioned, there is an issue with your eigenvectors.

For the eigenvalues / eigenvectors, you should have gotten:

$$\lambda_1 = 1+2i, v_1 = \left(\dfrac{1+i}{2},1\right)$$

$$\lambda_2 = 1-2i, v_2 = \left(\dfrac{1-i}{2},1\right)$$

If you want to see the final result for this system, hover over the following.

> $X(t) = \begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t) \end{bmatrix} = e^t\left(c_1 \begin{bmatrix} \cos 2 t + \sin 2 t \\ 2 \sin 2 t  \end{bmatrix} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix} -\sin 2 t \\  \cos 2 t - \sin 2 t \end{bmatrix}\right)$

Comment: Nice work and "hover" option! +1